# Proving the composition of two group homomorphisms is a group homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

> Prove that the composition of two group homomorphisms is a group homomorphism.

Let $f:G \longrightarrow G'$ and $g:G' \longrightarrow G''$ be two group homomorphisms.

Let $x$ and $y$ be two arbitrary elements of $G$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
(g \circ f)(x \cdot y) &=& g(f(x \cdot y)) \\
 &=& g(f(x) \cdot f(y)) \\
&=& g(f(x)) \cdot g(f(y)) \\
 &=& (g \circ f)(x) \cdot (g \circ f)(y)
\end{eqnarray}

This completes the proof - but which property of a group is used in the second step?
\begin{eqnarray}
g(f(x \cdot y)) &=& g(f(x) \cdot f(y)) \\
\end{eqnarray}

Is it a cauchy function? Is there another property that lets a group operation $ \cdot $ be pushed outside of a function?

Comment: in f(xy)=f(x)f(y) is used the fact that f is homomorphism.... from that implies g(f(xy))=g(f(x)f(y))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the composition of two group homomorphisms is a group homomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819096/prove-that-the-composition-of-two-group-homomorphisms-is-a-group-homomorphism)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *group homomorphism* is a map from a group $G$ to another group $G'$ that *preserves* the "group structure" (homomorphism are in general "structur-preserving maps"). This structure is the multiplication for multiplicative groups (addition for addivite groups). A homomorphism $f$ has then the defining property that for any $g,h \in G$:

$$f(g\cdot h) = f(g) \cdot' f(h)$$

where $\cdot$ denotes multiplication in $G$ and $\cdot'$ multiplication in $G'$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. To me this notation made it clearer. So using this we have
\begin{eqnarray}
(g \circ f)(x \cdot y) &=& g(f(x \cdot y)) \\
 &=& g(f(x) \cdot' f(y)) \\
&=& g(f(x)) \cdot'' g(f(y)) \\
 &=& (g \circ f)(x) \cdot'' (g \circ f)(y)
\end{eqnarray}

where $⋅''$ denotes multiplication in $G''$